# CakePHP unit tests only work once, then I have to reset database

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

I'm trying to get my team started making some unit tests for our application. The application is built on CakePHP.

To get started, I am building tests for our users table. I have the following Fixture to create a user for me to test against:

```
namespace App\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

class UsersFixture extends TestFixture
{
      public $connection = 'test';

      public $import = ['table' => 'users'];

      public $records = [
          [
              'username' => 'TestPass',
              'password' => '',
              'email' => 'TestPass@example.com',
              'status' => 'active',
              'created' => '2015-11-04 12:00:00',
              'last_logindate' => null,
              'registration_country' => 'AU',
              'system_user' => 0
          ]
      ];
}
```

I also have a TestCase for the table:

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Table\UsersTable;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

/**
 * App\Model\Table\UsersTable Test Case
 */
class UsersTableTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fixtures = [
        'app.Users'
    ];

    /**
     * setUp method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $config = TableRegistry::exists('Users') ? [] : ['className' => 'App\Model\Table\UsersTable'];
        $this->Users = TableRegistry::get('Users', $config);
    }

    /**
     * tearDown method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        unset($this->Users);

        parent::tearDown();
    }
    // ...
}
```

The first time I run this test it works perfectly. If I try to run it again then I get the following error:

PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

> Warning Error: Fixture creation for "users" failed "SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1101 BLOB/TEXT column 'status' can't
>   have a default value" in
>   [/path-to-app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/TestFixture.php,
>   line 232]
>
> Exception: Unable to insert fixtures for
>   "App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest" test case.
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'carebook_test.users' doesn't exist in
>   [/path-to-app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureManager.php,
>   line 253]

The only way for me to get rid of this error seems to be to DROP my database, recreate it and then run my migrations again. After that the test will run successfully another time, before breaking once more.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It seems like the reason for this is that once the test is concluded the table is dropped. But the test doesn't automatically create the table if it doesn't exist, so the test only runs once. I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so the table gets truncated instead of dropped. Or to make it so that Fixtures will create the table if it doesn't exist. Somewhat confused about how this is meant to work now, as I'd expect that this issue affects everyone.

EDIT2: I have discovered that CakePHP is indeed meant to create tables if they don't exist. The issue for me is that my column is an ENUM and CakePHP Fixtures don't support enum columns, so it makes it as a text column. Enum columns can have default values (and mine does) but text columns can't. So I think I have to figure out how to make CakePHP accept enum columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that CakePHP's extensions of the PHPUnit classes add functionality to drop the test tables after the tests have been run. On the next run of the test suite, Fixtures are used to recreate the tables.

This behaviour was not working for me as my database tables contained Enum columns. CakePHP does not support ENUM columns, and treats them as text columns instead. This meant that when the tables were recreated they had TEXT columns instead of ENUM columns.

This would've been okay, except that my ENUM columns had a default value, and on Windows MySQL trying to set a default value on a TEXT column causes an error. This tripped up CakePHP's test runner and prevented my tests from running.

A coworker and I together created a plugin for CakePHP which allows it to work properly with ENUM columns. This plugin is not currently publicly available but we have plans to release it as open source when work is less busy.

Answer (score 1):

> So I think I have to figure out how to make CakePHP accept enum columns.

Yes. CakePHP3 doesn't support enums by default because they won't work across all supported DB systems. Use the [Enum Plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/Enum) to get enum support.

- [How to work with Plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html)
- [How to configure additional types](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types)

Comment: As far as I can tell, that plugin doesn't seem to add database support for enums, but instead adds an enum class that gets stored in the database as integer still. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the enum problem can be ignored as long as the enum field plays no functional part in your test.

The missing table error is due to a 'new' caching feature in the DBO driver stack. DBO remembers the tables present at startup, and by default does not recognise dynamically created tables.

You can disable the caching of tables:

```
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Users = ClassRegistry::init('Users');
        $this->Users->setDataSource('test2');
        $this->Users->cacheSources = false;
    }
```